# How to Get the Next Class through each section of Uitableview?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview

In my Application i was using the different  UIButtons as menue to Go  Next class ,here is my Code

```
-(IBAction)GoToALevel
 {
ALevel *obj = [[ALevel alloc] initWithNibName:@"ALevel" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:obj animated:YES];
[obj release];
}
-(IBAction)GoToTLevel
{
TLevel *obj = [[TLevel alloc] initWithNibName:@"TLevel" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:obj animated:YES];
[obj release];
}
-(IBAction)GoToNLevel
 {
NLevel *obj = [[NLevel alloc] initWithNibName:@"NLevel" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:obj animated:YES];
[obj release];
 }
-(IBAction)GoToFLevel
 {
FLevel *obj = [[FLevel alloc] initWithNibName:@"FLevel" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:obj animated:YES];
[obj release];
  }
```

Now i put all these catogories in UITableview.But can any one Guide me that how can get the  Alevel when i click on first section of uitableview and so on .

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
      here is problem how to go next class 
   }
```

Comment: So, you have a table view filled with UIButtons in the cells? Did I understand it right?

Comment: No i have label in the Cell with Different Catagories.

Comment: And after pressing the cell, you would like to call the specific method, described upper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
switch (indexPath.row) {

    case 0:
        [self GoToALevel];
        break;
    case 1:
        [self GoToTLevel];
        break;
    case 2:
        [self GoToNLevel];
        break;
    case 3:
        [self GoToFLevel];
        break;

    default:
        break;
}
}
```

hope this helps. happy coding :)

Comment: You are welcome Lena. If possible can u upvote the answer too so as to help others in quick suggestion to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write this code in `DidSelectRowAtIndexPath()`. i.e

`-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`.

Here you can specify the action according to the method. Before this use the

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

to specify the what happens at the index of each cell i.e. `indexpath.row`.

Comment: I need at index 0 call Alevel at index 1 Call Tlevel.Thanx